# Xquery statement to get a value for specific name

Tags: xslt, xquery, name-value

I am trying to write a xquery to get the Value for a specific name .Below is the request payload: i.e. if the Name ="ID" then get the
"Value" for that tag (i.e.1000000000.)If the Name="User" get the "Value" for that tag( ie."US").

```
 <not:Items xmlns:v5="http://www.example.com"
xmlns:com="http://commom.com
xmlns:not="http://services.not.com"
xmlns:com1="http://common1.com">
<not:Array>
<com1:Item>
<v5:List>
<com:extensionsItem>
<com:Name>ID</com:Name>
<com:Value>1000000000</com:Value>
</com:extensionsItem>
<com:extensionsItem>
<com:Name>User</com:Name>
<com:Value>US</com:Value>
</com:extensionsItem>
</v5:List>
</com1:Item>
</not:Array>
</not:Items>
```

I tried the options below:

```
<ns2:ID>{fn:data($Items/not:Array/com1:Item/v5:List/com:extensionsItem[1]/com:Value)}<ID>
```

This statement works . But I cannot assure that ID will always come in first element in the array of List.So i want a statement that will work even if ID comes in any other
place in the array and I can retrieve the value.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply want to apply a predicate `$Items/not:Array/com1:Item/v5:List/com:extensionsItem[com:Name = 'ID']/com:Value`